# How to edit a Font in Windows 7 to increase line spacing in Eclipse?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, eclipse, truetype-fonts

In am trying to increase the *line spacing* in `Eclipse`, but to my surprise Eclipse does not have a build-in feature to increase line spacing, instead one has to edit the font to increase line spacing.

**My Question** is how to increase line spacing in eclipse by editing the font in `Windows-7`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free Font Editor for Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/28110/free-font-editor-for-windows)

Comment: Is your goal (of this question) to edit a font, or increase the line spacing in Eclipse?

Comment: @techie007 The goal is to increase line spacing in Eclipse at the same time I have spend few hours searching of this and found  the way to do it is to edit the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread [How can I change line height / line spacing in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014454/how-can-i-change-line-height-line-spacing-in-eclipse) deals with this problem.
The thread contains various semi-solutions, among which the best one might be to use the
font [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page).

The thread [Recommended Fonts for Programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming/6618#6618) contains more font recommendations.

In general, I don't believe you can change the line-height in Eclipse, so the most
you can do is change the font it uses.

If you cannot find a font you like, the next step is to modify an existing font
or make your own (maybe starting from a template).
The approaches you can take are :

1. Use a font editor. A quick google got me [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) (free) and [FontCreator](http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html) (commercial and costly, trial available). [Type light](http://cr8.netfirms.com/typelight.html) is a fully functional, freeware OpenType font editor.
2. Make your own font, using for example a website such as [FontStruct](http://fontstruct.com/) (free),
   [YourFonts](http://www.yourfonts.com/) (seems free) or [Fontifier](http://www.fontifier.com/) (9$).
3. Change the way Windows displays the screen (more info [here](http://windows7themes.net/how-to-increase-font-size-in-windows-7-improve-accessibility.html))

Comment: A very good blog about programming font by Jeff Atwood http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/revisiting-programming-fonts.html. Have you tried the solution in the link  How can I change line height / line spacing in Eclipse? before suggesting the solution?

Comment: I added more info on what I think is possible to do.